# How to invert z axis in a 3D plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization, mgcv

I have plotted a 3D perspective plot for generalized additive models. However, the Z-axis `Growers (proportion)` read from top to bottom. I see that is the default setting, but I'm interested in inverting the Z-axis to display values from bottom to top instead

Reproducible example:

```
n <- 200
sig2 <- 4
x1 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
x2 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
x3 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
x4 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
y <- x1^2 + x1 * x2 * x4

mod <- gam(y ~ s(x1, x2) + s(x3, x4))


p1 <- wrap_elements(panel = ~vis.gam(mod, view = c("x1",  "x2"), zlab = "Growers (proportion)", 
                                     theta = 120, plot.type = "persp", type = "response", ticktype = "detailed"))
p2 <- wrap_elements(panel = ~vis.gam(mod, view = c("x3",  "x4"), zlab = "Growers (proportion)", 
                                     theta = 35, plot.type = "persp", type = "response", ticktype = "detailed"))

fig <- p1 + p2 + plot_layout(ncol = 2, tag_level = 'new') +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = list(c('(a)', '(b)'))) 
fig
```

Here is the current plot. As you can see, the Z-axis `Growers (proportion)` reads from top to bottom. Can we somehow invert the Z-axis?

[image]

Comment: `vis.gam` uses `persp`, which doesn't seem to support the "normal" way of passing `zlim = c(1, 0)0`. But if these are actually proportions between 0 and 1, you could model the inverse, so the proportion of "not growers".

Comment: The other option you have is rotating the viewing angle by 180 degrees by setting `phi = -180` inside `vis.gam`. This reverses the z axis, but also puts the other two axes at the top of  the box, which tends to make them clash with the plot. This is your only other option though, apart from doing as @Axeman says, or changing to use plotly, which will create pretty 3D surfaces with nice axes too.

Comment: @AllanCameron Is there a way to directly plot `gam` model output in plotly? Could you please share the code? Thanks

Comment: Your example isn't exactly reproducible -- you don't include the `library()` calls.  We can guess them from the tags, but it's better to actually include reproducible examples.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "reads from top to bottom".  Are you just talking about the z-axis label, or the values?  I see high values at the top, not the bottom.

Comment: I am talking about the label `Growers (proportion)`

Comment: I don't think `persp` supports rotating that text to the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the rule for both `vis.gam()` (which uses `persp()`) and `plot_ly()` is that the text will appear parallel to the axis, with the direction chosen so that the top of the text appears above the text in the plot.

With the orientation you chose for the plots, the z-axis tilts to the left when moving upwards, so the top of the text will be chosen to be towards the axis.  If you change the orientation of the display by enough to have the axis tilt to the right, the text will switch orientations.  For example:

```r
library(mgcv)
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> This is mgcv 1.9-0. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.
n <- 200
sig2 <- 4
x1 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
x2 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
x3 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
x4 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
y <- x1^2 + x1 * x2 * x4

mod <- gam(y ~ s(x1, x2) + s(x3, x4))

vis.gam(mod, view = c("x1",  "x2"), zlab = "Growers (proportion)", 
                                     theta = 120, phi = -15, plot.type = "persp", type = "response", ticktype = "detailed")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I don't think the orientation I've chosen is particularly good.  If you want to find a good one using `persp()`, you'll have a lot of trial and error.

`plot_ly()` may have an option to flip the text; I'm pretty sure `persp()` doesn't.